# Can't find fields using FindControl in a FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I wonder if anyone can help me with this. I've been searching for answers and get so far but think I'm missing something.

I have a FormView that was created using Dynamic Data. Within that FormView I have 3 fields, ItemCosts, AdditionalCosts and TotalCosts. I would like to be able to put a button on the form that adds the ItemsCosts and AdditionalCosts together and displays it in the TotalCosts textbox. Simple enough... so I thought.

I've discovered I need to use ItemCommand as the FormView uses this command when posting back. This is what I have written:

HTML

```
 <asp:Panel ID="DetailsPanel" runat="server">
                <br /><br />
                <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="DetailsDataSource" RenderOuterTable="false"
                    OnPreRender="FormView1_PreRender" OnModeChanging="FormView1_ModeChanging" OnItemUpdated="FormView1_ItemUpdated"
                    OnItemInserted="FormView1_ItemInserted" OnItemDeleted="FormView1_ItemDeleted" OnItemCommand="FormView1_ItemCommand" OnDataBinding="FormView1_DataBind">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table id="detailsTable" class="DDDetailsTable" cellpadding="6">
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr class="td">
                        <td class="DDLightHeader">Order No</td>
                        <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="OrderNo" runat="server" DataField="OrderNo" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="td">
                        <td class="DDLightHeader">Item Costs</td>
                        <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="ItemCosts" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="td">
                        <td class="DDLightHeader">AdditionalCosts</td>
                        <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="AdditionalCosts" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="td">
                        <td class="DDLightHeader">Total Costs</td>
                        <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="TotalCosts" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="td">
                           <td colspan="2">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
                                    OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");' />  
 </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                     <tr class="td">
                        <td class="DDLightHeader">Order No</td>
                        <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="OrderNo" runat="server" DataField="OrderNo" Mode="ReadOnly"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="td">
                        <td class="DDLightHeader">Item Costs</td>
                        <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="ItemCosts" Mode="Edit" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="td">
                        <td class="DDLightHeader">Additional Costs</td>
                        <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="AdditionalCosts" Mode="Edit" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="td">
                        <td class="DDLightHeader">Total Costs</td>
                        <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="TotalCosts" Mode="Edit"  /></td>
                        <td><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCalculateTotalCosts" Text="Calculate total costs" CommandName="Calculate" /></td>
                    </tr>                    
                    <tr class="td">
                        <td class="DDLightHeader">View Items</td>
                        <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="tblCateringOrdersDetailsItems" Mode="Edit" /></td>
                    </tr>
                       <tr class="td">
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DynamicEntity ID="DynamicEntity3" runat="server" Mode="Insert" />
                        <tr class="td">
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton7" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:FormView>

                <asp:EntityDataSource ID="DetailsDataSource" runat="server" EnableDelete="true" EnableInsert="true" EnableUpdate="true" />

                <asp:QueryExtender ID="QueryExtender1" TargetControlID="DetailsDataSource" runat="server">
                    <asp:ControlFilterExpression ControlID="GridView1" />
                </asp:QueryExtender>
            </asp:Panel>
```

I've added a btnCalculateTotalCosts button in the EditTemplate section.

In the code behind I've created an ItemCommand control

```
protected void FormView1_ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Calculate")
            {
                FormViewRow row = FormView1.Row;
                decimal itemCosts;
                decimal additionalCosts;

                TextBox itemsCostTextBox = (TextBox)row.FindControl("ItemCosts");
                TextBox additionalCostsTextBox = (TextBox)row.FindControl("AdditionalCosts");
                TextBox totalCostsTextBox = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TotalCosts");

                Decimal.TryParse(itemsCostTextBox.Text, out itemCosts);
                Decimal.TryParse(additionalCostsTextBox.Text, out additionalCosts);

                totalCostsTextBox.Text = (itemCosts + additionalCosts).ToString();
}
```

But I keep getting an 'error Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.  I've read that you have to bind the fields to the FormView first so I tried to create the following

```
 protected void FormView1_DataBind(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
            {
                TextBox itemsCostTextBox = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("ItemCosts");
                TextBox additionalCostsTextBox = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("AdditionalCosts");
                TextBox totalCostsTextBox = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("TotalCosts");
            }
        }
```

and reference the DataBind in the  tag as OnDataBinding="FormView1_DataBind" but this didn't work either and I'm getting the same error.

I really have tried to work this out and realise that the FindControl is not 'seeing' the fields in FormView but I just can't work out how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824316/asp-net-accessing-child-controls-in-a-formview-control would appear to be a very similar question.  http://forums.asp.net/t/1421731.aspx may also be a useful link to consider.

Answer (score 0):

`FindControl()` receives the `ID` for the control you are looking for. From ASPX code you posted I'm not seeing that you are setting the `ID` property for `DynamicControl`s you are trying to find using `FindControl()`. This call to that method:

```
TextBox itemsCostTextBox = (TextBox)row.FindControl("ItemCosts");
```

is passing the `DataField` property value instead of the `ID`. Add the `ID` property to all `DynamicControl`s that you want to find.

Also take into account that `FindControl()` does not perform a recursive search, it only looks for a control with the specified `ID` between the control's children.

Comment: Thank you so much juan.facorro. It didn't occur to me that the ID was missing. I have now added the ID but am now getting the following error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.DynamicData.DynamicControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'". Do you have any advice on this? All the examples I've read seem to suggest I can do it that way I have in my example. Thanks again. Much appreciated.

Comment: The controls you are declaring in the ASPX are `DynamicControl`s so the cast should be to this type. I'm not sure how the examples you've seen handle the `DynamicControl`s, but there's some incompatibitility in the way you are declaring your controls and the way you want to handle them in `ItemCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else:

```
    protected void FormView1_ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Calculate")
        {
            // ...            
            //instead of this...
            TextBox itemsCostTextBox = (TextBox)row.FindControl("ItemCosts");
            //(no need to use row here, just use the reference to the FormView;
            //also no need to add an ID to DynamicControl because it creates
            //its own ID out of the field name and template control name)

            //cast like this...
            var itemsCostTextBox = (TextBox)FormView1.FindFieldTemplate("ItemCosts").TemplateControl.FindControl("txtTextBox1");
            //txtTextBox1 is the name of the specific web UI control inside of
            //the DynamicData *.ascx template that you want access to
        }
    }
```